# How do I call DSOperationType.REMOVE to remove the selected record from a drop-down grid?

Tags: datasource, smartgwt

I am trying to delete the selected record from the drop-down grid.

In trying to do this, I've so far learned that `DSOperationType.FETCH` is called when the `fetchData()` method is called on `ValuesManager` class. So now I want to know what line should be executed for calling `DSOperationType.REMOVE`.

Or is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Answer (score 0):

DSOperationType.REMOVE will be called only when removing data/row from list grid or tree grid. It can be triggered functionally by calling ListGrid.removeData(someData) or ListGrid.removeSelectedData();

But for ComboBox/SelectBox (DropDown) type item there is no functionality to remove data from list as it can only be selected from a list of data (while loading data for list FETCH operation will be called).

You can implement the functionlity indirectly by using Combobox/SelectItem with listgrid  - (ex:http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#dropdown_grid_combobox_category). In listgrid you can have remove data functionality. Also check other types of functionality that can be implemented with combobx http://www.smartclient.com/smartgwt/showcase/#multi_select_combobox_category